# Django: Prefetch_related on nested attributes

Tags: django, prefetch

I need to list all my devices. To do this I use a prefetch related to reduce the amount of queries. But one of them is consuming to much time.. I wonder if it can't go better.

I will start with the model constructions: I want a list of devices.

```
class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

class GatewayDevice(models.Model):
    gateway = models.ForeignKey(
        Gateway, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="devices"
    )
    device = models.ForeignKey(
        Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="gatewaydevices"
    )
```

In the real code the device model is larger, but that code is irrelevant. As you can see, a device has some gatewaydevices (which is a model between gateway and device)

So in my list of devices, I want for every device, the linked gateway.

This is my view:

```
class AdminDeviceView(GenericAPIView):
    def get_permissions(self):
        return IsAuthenticated()

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return AdminDeviceInfoSerializer

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        responses={
            200: openapi.Response(
                _("Successfully fetched all data from devices."),
                AdminDeviceInfoSerializer,
            )
        }
    )

    def get(self, request):
    """
    GET the data from all the devices.
    """

    devices = (
        Device.objects.filter()
        .all()
        .prefetch_related(
            "site__users",
            "software_update_history",
            "supplier",
            Prefetch(
                "gatewaydevices",
                queryset=GatewayDevice.objects.filter(end_date=None)
                .order_by()
                .distinct()
                .prefetch_related("gateway"),
            ),
        )
    )

    serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
    serializer = serializer_class(devices, many=True)
    devices_data = serializer.data

    return Response(
        {"total": devices.count(), "items": devices_data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK
    )
```

This is the part of the serializer that is important:

```
@staticmethod
def get_gateway(device):
    return (
        GatewaySimpleSerializer(device.gatewaydevices.gateway).data
        if device.gatewaydevices.gateway
        else None
    )
```

I tried different approaches. This one is the current one.. Now I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'gateway'
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should be able to use `.select_related("gateway")` rather than `.prefetch_related("gateway")`. This should save you a query.

Your problem appears to be here:

```py
if device.gatewaydevices.gateway
```

Here, `gatewaydevices` is not a single model instance, so it doesn't have the gateway property. I'm not exactly sure what your use case is, but there can be multiple `gatewaydevices`. Maybe you want the first (this will fail if there are zero `gatewaydevices`):

```py
if device.gatewaydevices.first().gateway
```

Perhaps you want to know if there are any. This should work:

```py
if device.gatewaydevices.filter(gateway__isnull=False)
```

This seems strange though, it feels like this code should be with the rest of the query if you want to exclude objects without `gateway`s. I think you should just remove the `if` completely and always return the data. You're not saving any database time doing this.

Based on the further comment:

```py
if device.gatewaydevices.filter(end_date__isnull=True).first()
```

A (possibly) better way to write the query if you're trying to avoid extra work:

```py
gateway_devices = (
    GatewayDevice.objects
    .filter(end_date__isnull=True)
    .select_related("gateway", "device")
)
```

This will get everything in one query and you can just use simple attribute access to get the related objects without any extra queries, such as:

```py
for gateway_device in gateway_devices:
   print(gateway_device.device.name)
```

Looking at your models (though I can't see everything I need to write this perfectly) it looks like you also want some info from `Device` relations, so you might need to tweak this to have `device` prefetch what you need, something like:

```py
gateway_devices = (
    GatewayDevice.objects
    .filter(end_date_isnull=True)
    .select_related("gateway")
    .prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            "device",
            queryset=Device.objects.prefetch_related(
                # Depending how these are related you may be able to
                # save some queries using `select_related()` instead.
                "site__users", "software_update_history", "supplier"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This might not be perfect, but it should give you what you need to make a good start.

Comment: There is no other way to get the gatewaydevice by doing .first()?

Comment: There are other ways, sure, but it depends what you want to do. The problem is that there can be any number of gatewaydevices, and it's not exactly clear what your logic is supposed to be.

Comment: As you can see it refers to "GatewayDevice". That's a table in SQL, where a device can be linked to many gateways. But for every device there is only one gateway with no "end_date", that's the current one. I just need to display that gateway, for every device

Comment: I added something to the answer for that. You can either use `.frst()` or `.get()`. The difference is that `.get()` will raise an exception if there's no matching row.

Comment: But it's not possible to do that last .first() in the query to reduce amount of queries?

Comment: Hmm it's hard to say. It's not really clear if there even _is_ an extra query, since you're prefetching it. Maybe it'd work with `gatewaydevices[0]`, `.first()` might force a query.The other option would be to annotate the data you want into your query and use it from there. Perhaps an even better way might be to "invert" your query, i.e. query for `Gateway.objects.filter(...)`, you should be able to use combinations of `prefetch/select_related` and filtering to get your data this way. Then you can access the other objects through simple attribute access, which won't generate new queries.

Comment: something like this?
        devices = (
            Device.not_deleted_objects.filter(delivery_status=Device.RECEIVED)
            .select_related("gatewaydevices")
            .prefetch_related(
                "site__users",
                "software_update_history",
                "supplier",
                Prefetch(
                    "gateway",
                    queryset=Gateway.objects.filter(
                        devices__end_date=None
                    ).prefetch_related("gateway"),
                ),
            )
        )

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why all attributes are None (from Device & gateway)

Comment: No, sorry. It should get the correct attributes from your objects. Could be your data, or something else.

Comment: Strange enough, this approach is taking much longer time

Comment: Maybe because my device class is so large