# Django initial loading of page taking too long

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Hi I am a beginner at Django and I am working on a project that lists 100 companies in each page along with there contacts and also the amount of items sold. Here is an example:

[image]

As you can see the initial loading time of the page is very high. But when I refresh the page it refreshes very fast because I am using caching.

Here are some of my other files:

**models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    bic = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)

    def get_order_count(self):
        orders = self.orders.count()
        return orders

    def get_order_sum(self):
        orders = Order.objects.filter(company=self)
        total_sum = sum([x.total for x in orders])
        return total_sum

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']


class Contact(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, related_name="contacts", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def get_order_count(self):
        orders = self.orders.count()
        return orders


class Order(models.Model):
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name="orders", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name="orders", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=9)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   
    added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.order_number
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import ListView
from mailer.models import Company, Contact, Order


class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = "mailer/index.html"
    model = Company
    paginate_by = 100
```

**The html**

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-borderless">
    {% if is_paginated %}
    <tr><td>
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" class="pager-prev{% if not page_obj.has_previous %} inactive{% endif %}">&laquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="pager-next{% if not page_obj.has_next %} inactive{% endif %}">&raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Order Count</th>
        <th>Order Sum</th>
        <th>Select</th>
    </tr>
        {% for company in company_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ company.get_order_count }}</td>
            <td>{{ company.get_order_sum|floatformat:2 }}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="select{{company.pk}}" id=""></td>
        </tr>
            {% for contact in company.contacts.all %}
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>{{ contact.first_name }} {{ contact.last_name }}</td>
                <td>Orders: {{ contact.get_order_count }}</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    </div>
```

Is there any way in which I can reduce the initial load time. Please show me an efficient way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `{{company.get_order_count}}` will hit the DB. Admittedly with a very simple query, but even so, it will slow things down.

You want to annotate the objects with this count. Use

```
from django.db.models import Count

class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = "mailer/index.html"
    model = Company
    paginate_by = 100

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate( num_orders=Count('orders') )
```

and replace `{{ company.get_order_count }}` with `{{ company.num_orders }}`. This will turn N+1 DB queries into one DB query.

That's the easy one. There's  a similar problem with `get_order_sum` which can almost certainly be solved with another annotation involving the `django.db.Sum`. Sorry but its late and my stomach is growling and I don't have any confidence that I would get that one right straight off the top of my head.

The cheat sheet on annotation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/). You might also need to look at aggregation.

Oh, and install [Django_debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in your developer environment. Every time in future it gets slow, you can just click there to see what SQL was executed and how long it took.

Comment: The individual orders of the contacts of each company are not showing anymore, something went wrong.

Comment: Wierd. Don't understand that. `company.contacts.all` should be completely unaffected. It's another N queries, though, which can be fixed by adding `.prefetch_related('contacts')` to the queryset.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Cut and pasted wrong line from your template. The annotation fixed `company.get_order_count` not contact. Will edit my response. I don't know how to annotate prefetched contacts ... experience with Django ORM teaches that often what you think is impossible, is merely mind-bendingly twisted. It might well be worth another question specifically about that.

Comment: Ok will try these things in a few hours thanks. I will share if I run into more problems.

Comment: Thank you the load time has decreased significantly from 50000ms to 8000ms. This what I have done now `return super().get_queryset().prefetch_related('contacts__orders').annotate( num_orders=Count('orders') ).order_by('-id')`. If there is any way to reduce the loading time any more please let me know.

Comment: Here is the sql query that is taking up most of the time now `SELECT "mailer_order"."id",
       "mailer_order"."order_number",
       "mailer_order"."company_id",
       "mailer_order"."contact_id",
       "mailer_order"."total",
       "mailer_order"."order_date",
       "mailer_order"."added_date",
       "mailer_order"."modified_date"
  FROM "mailer_order"
 WHERE "mailer_order"."company_id" = '191'` 100 similar queries. From django debug toolbar.

Comment: I think that the remaining problem is `{{ contact.get_order_count }}` being iterated in the template. (Try removing that to see if the 100 similar queries disappear). I have a feeling that the answer may be in the complicated queryset using a `Prefetch` object here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61657095/django-prefetch-related-on-nested-attributes. I don't have the time to fully understand this, so I may be wrong. (The question is actually about something completely different)